# Multiple Timezones - Clock

Tags: javascript, time, offset, clock, digital

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clock in different time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883441/clock-in-different-time-zones)

I've been looking *everywhere* and can't seem to find a simple solution for this.

I'm looking to show **multiple timezones** say New York, Rio, London, etc. in **24hr mode.**

[Sort of like this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Nxh.png)

I know this can be done in good old javascript but no idea where to start. I'm most likely gonna be showing more than 3 timezones, so something that is easy to change & customise would be the bomb.

Please help & thank you in advance!

Comment: have you read [`date.js`](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883441/clock-in-different-time-zones

Comment: hey thanks, was able to figure out a simple solution! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Date instance. Use [`setMinutes`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.32) to set the time based on the difference between the local time zone offset (available using [`getTimezoneOffset`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26)) and the offset of whatever other time zone you wish.

I suggest minutes because the time zone offset it returned as minutes to add to the current time to get UTC. So to get the time for somewhere that is UTC-04:00 (New York):

```
var d = new Date();
var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
var targetOffset = -4*60;
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + offset + targetOffset);
```

Note that this just sets the time so that methods like `getHours`, `getMinutes`, etc. return adjusted values, the date object still has a local time zone offset and may have errors over daylight saving boundaries.

Comment: Be very careful with this.  A "time zone" and a "time zone offset" are two different things.  -4 is only the offset in New York for part of the year (during the summer). The rest of the year, the offset is -5.